# oracle select records today but exclude those which may exist in the previous days

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

two records should exist in a table in oracle, one is from the request and the other is from the response.

i would like to select all those records from today but the problem is the other pair might be existing from the previous two days or more.

how do i ensure that the records that will be returned are only 1 and will not exist in the previous days

`select A.referenceNum, A.datetime, A.Type from table A where A.datetime >= sysdate - 1`

To visualize, i would like to select only **reference num 789ef**.

ReferenceNum  DateTime  Type

123ab         (datetoday)  Request

123ab         (datetoday)  Response

456cd         (datetoday)  Request

456cd         (datetoday-2)  Response

789ef         (datetoday)  Request

Comment: If the ReferenceNum is sequential, all you need is `select max(A.referenceNum), A.datetime, A.Type from table A where A.datetime >= sysdate - 1 group by A.datetime`. If there are too many records, performance may not be the best.

Comment: yes, there are too many records.. and the reference is nvarchar..  i will modify the reference num in the question

Comment: I'd try something like this:

    `SELECT * FROM table
     WHERE datetime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD')
       AND referencenum IN (  SELECT referencenum
                                FROM table
                            GROUP BY referencenum
                              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)`

Comment: So is 789 selected because its numeric component (assuming always the leading characters and two alpha chars as suffix, or is the format variabgle?) is the highest value for the day?  What indexes exist, and can you add indexes?

Comment: ah no, 789ef should be selected because it has no matching response yet as of today and yesterday

Comment: trying out the suggestions.. will get back to you guys wait thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single table scan (compared to using `NOT EXISTS` which will use two table scans) using analytic functions:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddd8cd/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ReferenceNum,  DateTime,  Type ) AS
SELECT '123ab', SYSDATE, 'Request' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123ab', SYSDATE, 'Response' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456cd', SYSDATE, 'Request' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '456cd', SYSDATE - 2, 'Response' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '789ef', SYSDATE, 'Request' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ReferenceNum
FROM   ( 
  SELECT ReferenceNum,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN TRUNC( DateTime ) =  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY ReferenceNum ) AS num_today,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN TRUNC( DateTime ) <> TRUNC( SYSDATE ) THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY ReferenceNum ) AS num_other_day
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  num_today = 1
AND    num_other_day = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddd8cd/11/0)**:

```
| REFERENCENUM |
|--------------|
|        789ef |
```

Comment: I have chosen this as an answer because it returns the answer in a timely manner compared to the other 2

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` operator

```
SELECT A.referenceNum, A.datetime, A.Type 
from table A 
   where A.datetime >= sysdate - 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT null FROM table B
     WHERE A.referenceNum = B.referenceNum
       AND b.datetime < a.datetime
  )
```

Comment: sorry, the results returned too long even if I tried to add more where conditions. thanks still so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT referenceNum
FROM A A1
WHERE TRUNC(A1.datetime) > TRUNC(sysdate)-1
AND A1.Type              = 'Request'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM A
  WHERE TRUNC(A.datetime) >= TRUNC(sysdate)-1
  AND A.Type               = 'Response'
  AND A.referenceNum       = A1.referenceNum
  )
```

Comment: sorry, the results returned too long even if I tried to add more where conditions. thanks still so much for the help!